# Hook 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation' never triggered

Tags: wordpress

I use the latest WordPress 6.4 and WooCommerce 8.3 -- both clean install on my localhost.

This is the code:

```
  add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'zk123_test');
```

The script is called and the action is added correctly.
The action is never triggered, but for example this works:

```
  add_action('woocommerce_shipping_init', 'zk123_test');
```

I have the default theme StoreFront.

I've spent 3 hours on this and I feel frustrated.

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently there have been changes since WC 8.4 that use some blocks, so the PHP hooks are never triggered!
I think I have to use Javascript instead(?) or switch the theme blocks to some "legacy mode" that will make the hooks work again.

1. [Checkout blocks (documentation)](https://woo.com/document/cart-checkout-blocks-status/#section-8)
2. [Currently supported hooks](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-blocks/blob/3ad662163e286937eec9be5d27193a7206e3dd5e/docs/third-party-developers/extensibility/hooks/actions.md)